# Problems with page number position after \newgeometry

Tags: page-numbering, geometry, page

I am having a wide table, so I decided to use `\newgeometry{left=12mm,right=12mm,top=12mm,footskip=0.5in}` before the beginning of that table to make it fit the page. After the table ending, I removed it with `\restoregeometry`. The problem is that whenever I apply `\newgeometry`, the page number shifts from the usual position (at the bottom of the page, centered) to the top-right corner and I cannot move it back to the bottom. I tried adjusting footskip (as you can see in `\newgeometry` options), but that does not work either. It seems that there is enough space at the bottom below the table, so I cannot see where is the problem. The code is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, bm} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage[
singlelinecheck=false 
]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{natbib} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 


\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}
\captionsetup[table]{skip=4pt}
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{threeparttable} 
\usepackage{floatpag}
\usepackage{geometry}




\newenvironment{spmatrix}[1]
 {\def\mysubscript{#1}\mathop\bgroup\begin{bmatrix}}
 {\end{bmatrix}\egroup_{\textstyle\mathstrut\scriptstyle\mysubscript}}


\hypersetup{pdfstartview={XYZ null null 1.00},bookmarksnumbered,hypertexnames=false} 

\setlength\parindent{34pt}
\onehalfspacing

\title{}




\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\clubpenalty 9999 %no orphants (typographic properties)
\widowpenalty 9999 %no widows (typographic properties)
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi} %shortcut for Stata tables

\maketitle



\newpage
\onehalfspacing

\section{Table}

\newgeometry{left=12mm,right=12mm,top=12mm,footskip=0.5in}
\begin{table}
\begin{footnotesize}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l *{7}{c}}
\toprule \toprule
forecast  & forecast & \multicolumn{6}{c}{proportion of forecast error variance $h$ periods ahead accounted for by innovations in} \\ \cline{3-8}
error     & horizon  & \multirow{2}{*}{real GDP} & \multirow{2}{*}{house prices} & \multirow{2}{*}{residential investment} & \multirow{2}{*}{CPI} & \multirow{2}{*}{mortgage rate} & \multirow{2}{*}{policy rate} \\
in        & $h$      &         &         &         &         &           &          \\
\midrule
real GDP  &   6      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
          &  12      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
          &  18      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
          &  24      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
          &  30      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
          &  36      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
          &  60      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
\hline
house prices &   6      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
          &  12      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
          &  18      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
          &  24      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
          &  30      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
          &  36      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
          &  60      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
\hline
residential investment  &   6      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
          &  12      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
          &  18      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
          &  24      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
          &  30      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
          &  36      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
          &  60      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
\hline
CPI  &   6      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
          &  12      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
          &  18      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
          &  24      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
          &  30      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
          &  36      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
          &  60      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
\hline
mortgage rate  &   6      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
          &  12      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
          &  18      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
          &  24      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
          &  30      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
          &  36      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
          &  60      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
\hline
policy rate  &   6      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
          &  12      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
          &  18      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
          &  24      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
          &  30      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
          &  36      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
          &  60      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{}
\label{}
\end{center}
\end{footnotesize}
\end{table}

\restoregeometry


\end{document}
```

Comment: there is no need for newgeometry at all, just use `\hspace*{-2cm}\begin{tabular}.....\end{tabular}\hspace*{-2cm}` (or better, adjust the  table to fit within the normal margins)

Comment: The header and footer (page number) are a function of the page style.  \pagestyle{plain} should be at the bottom.

Comment: Neither of this helps. If I use \hspace*{-2cm‌​} the table nicely fit the page without the need for \newgeometry, but the page number still appears on the top-right of the page, and with \pagestyle{plain}  it is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
\begin{table}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}%
 \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{l *{7}{c}}
    [...]
    \end{tabular}%
}
\caption{}
\label{}
\end{table}
```

then you do not needed a new page setting. Now the complete code for your example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, bm} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{natbib} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}
\captionsetup[table]{skip=4pt}
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{threeparttable} 
\usepackage{floatpag}
\usepackage{geometry}
\newenvironment{spmatrix}[1]
{\def\mysubscript{#1}\mathop\bgroup\begin{bmatrix}}
    {\end{bmatrix}\egroup_{\textstyle\mathstrut\scriptstyle\mysubscript}}
\hypersetup{pdfstartview={XYZ null null 1.00},bookmarksnumbered,hypertexnames=false} 

\setlength\parindent{34pt}
\onehalfspacing
\title{}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
    \clubpenalty 9999 %no orphants (typographic properties)
    \widowpenalty 9999 %no widows (typographic properties)
    \def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi} %shortcut for Stata tables   
    \maketitle
    \newpage
    \onehalfspacing

\section{Table}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\footnotesize
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
\begin{tabular}{l *{7}{c}}\toprule \toprule
    forecast  & forecast & \multicolumn{6}{c}{proportion of forecast error variance $h$ 
    periods ahead accounted for by innovations in} \\ \cline{3-8}
    error     & horizon  & \multirow{2}{*}{real GDP} & \multirow{2}{*}{house prices} & 
    \multirow{2}{*}{residential investment} & \multirow{2}{*}{CPI} & 
    \multirow{2}{*}{mortgage rate} & \multirow{2}{*}{policy rate} \\
    in        & $h$      &         &         &         &         &           &          \\
    \midrule
    real GDP  &   6      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
    &  12      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
    &  18      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
    &  24      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
    &  30      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
    &  36      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
    &  60      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\\hline
    house prices &   6      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
    &  12      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
    &  18      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
    &  24      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
    &  30      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
    &  36      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
    &  60      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\\hline
    residential investment  &   6      &         &         &         &         &           
    &        \\
    &  12      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
    &  18      &         &         &         &         &           &        \\
                    &  24      &         &         &         &         &           
                    &        \\
                    &  30      &         &         &         &         &           
                    &        \\
                    &  36      &         &         &         &         &           
                    &        \\
                    &  60      &         &         &         &         &           
                    &        \\
                    \hline
                    CPI  &   6      &         &         &         &         &           
                    &        \\
                    &  12      &         &         &         &         &           
                    &        \\
                    &  18      &         &         &         &         &           
                    &        \\
                    &  24      &         &         &         &         &           
                    &        \\
                    &  30      &         &         &         &         &           
                    &        \\
                    &  36      &         &         &         &         &           
                    &        \\
                    &  60      &         &         &         &         &           
                    &        \\
                    \hline
                    mortgage rate  &   6      &         &         &         &         
                    &           &        \\
                    &  12      &         &         &         &         &           
                    &        \\
                    &  18      &         &         &         &         &           
                    &        \\
                    &  24      &         &         &         &         &           
                    &        \\
                    &  30      &         &         &         &         &           
                    &        \\
                    &  36      &         &         &         &         &           
                    &        \\
                    &  60      &         &         &         &         &           
                    &        \\
                    \hline
                    policy rate  &   6      &         &         &         &         
                    &           &        \\
                    &  12      &         &         &         &         &           
                    &        \\
                    &  18      &         &         &         &         &           
                    &        \\
                    &  24      &         &         &         &         &           
                    &        \\
                    &  30      &         &         &         &         &           
                    &        \\
                    &  36      &         &         &         &         &           
                    &        \\
                    &  60      &         &         &         &         &           
                    &        \\
                    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
}
\captionof{table}{A Caption}\label{aLabel}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This shows me an error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item, so it maybe thinks that I am trying to make some numbered list....

Comment: see edited answer

Comment: Yes, this is working! Thank you very much. Do you please know if there would be similar procedure with large figures, for which I am also applying \newgeometry to make them fit the page? I have tried this minipage to work with figures, but it doesn't.

Comment: It works also with a `\includegraphics` instead of the complete `\resizebox{...}`